# Weighing the edges based on their connections and the overall amount of edges

Tags: r, data-visualization, igraph, edges, graph-visualization

I have a graph

```
+ edges from a5dfe4f:
  [1] 2->4 5->4 2->4 2->1 2->4 5->4 2->4 3->4 1->4 2->3 5->4 2->5 5->2 3->4 2->1 1->4 2->4 3->4 3->4 5->4 5->2 1->2 2->5 3->5 2->4 1->4 1->4 5->4 3->4 3->4 2->4 2->5 1->4 3->1
 [35] 2->5 5->2 1->2 2->1 1->4 4->1 5->4 5->4 2->4 2->4 1->2 5->4 4->2 2->4 2->4 2->4 2->4 5->4 2->4 2->4 5->4 2->4 1->4 2->4 2->4 2->4 3->4 2->1 2->1 1->4 2->4 1->3 2->4 3->4
 [69] 2->4 2->4 1->4 2->4 3->4 2->4 2->4 4->2 2->3 5->2 2->3 5->2 2->3 3->2 1->2 2->1 5->2 5->3 3->2 1->2 3->2 5->2 5->3 1->3 2->3 1->2 1->2 5->2 3->1 1->2 3->5 1->3 1->2 4->5
[103] 5->2 5->1 2->5 2->5 1->5 5->3 4->5 2->5 2->5 2->3 5->3 2->3 5->2 2->3 1->3 2->1 2->1 3->1 2->5 1->2 1->5 2->1 3->1 2->3 2->3 1->2 3->1 2->3 2->5 4->3 2->1 5->3 2->1 5->3
[137] 2->1 3->1 1->5 2->5 1->3 3->1 5->3 1->5 2->5 1->3 5->3 3->5 1->3 1->5 5->3 2->5 5->3 1->5 2->5 3->5 1->3 3->5 2->1 1->5 3->5 2->5 2->5 5->1 2->5 1->5 3->5 5->1 1->5
```

When I plot it I receive multiple edges as expected. However, I was asked to present one graph and I thought that basing the width of plotted edges on the weight would be more visually explanatory. What I wanted to do was to add a weight to each of the edges which indicates (number of edges between 1 and 2)/number of all the edges. Then I would want to add this kind of a proportion to all the edges. However, I'm having problems with specifying which edges I would want to apply this weight to. For now the graph looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc2t7.png) but it doesn't really show how this graph is different from others. I couldn't find any similar question or a manual that would explain how to do this. Therefore, I would be very grateful for any kind of suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I managed to answer this question. What I do is put together ID of the first node with the ID of the second node using paste function. The edges object looks like this and it's what the graph in the question was created from:

```
eeu1[[1]]
   PLAYERID value
1         2     4
2         4     2
6         4     3
7         5     4
17        4     3
23        4     2
29        4     1
31        2     3
36        4     5
47        4     5
53        4     5
59        4     5
61        2     5
```

Then, the number specifies which node the connection comes from and which node it goes to. The loop looks like this:

```
for(i in 1:379){
  weeu1[[i]]<-as.data.frame(paste(eeu1[[i]][,1],eeu1[[i]][,2], sep=""))
  coneu1[[i]]<-nrow(weeu1[[i]])
}
```

In this situation weeu1 stores the objects in which 12 represents a connection between 1 and 2. 31 would represent an edge 3->1 and so on. Coneu1 stores the amount of connections. I create a vector which contains numerics to represent the connections for team 1 and for team 2 but, in this example we only use team 1. Therefore, the vector looks like this:

```
t1con<-setdiff(c(12:54),c(16:20,22,26:30,33,36:40,44,46:50,55))
```

I exclude numbers that are impossible to represent a connection since a node with ID=1 cannot connect with a node that has ID>5 because, IDs from 1 to 5 represent team 1 and IDs between 6 and 10 represent team 2. Then, I use this loop for the calculation of weights:

```
for(h in 1:379){#EU1
  for(i in 1:coneu1[[h]]){
    for(j in t1con){
      if(weeu1[[h]][i,1]==j){
        weeu1[[h]][i,2]<-length(which(weeu1[[h]]==j))/nrow(weeu1[[h]])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, I create graphs as the one in the question with:

```
for (i in 1:379){
  geu1[[i]] <- graph_from_edgelist(eeu1[[i]])
}
```

And lastly I follow it up with a loop that adds the weight attribute to each of the existing connections. In this loop I also simplify the graphs in order to not have repeated edges that have the same weight.

```
for(i in 1:379){
  geu1[[i]]<-set.edge.attribute(graph = geu1[[i]],name = "weight",value = weeu1[[i]][,2])
  geu1[[i]]<-simplify(geu1[[i]],remove.multiple = T)
}
```

In the end, I have graphs with singular weighted edges instead of having multiple binary connections. I hope it comes in handy to somebody.